# syn::ItemStruct not found on root

Tags: parsing, rust, syn

I am trying to use `syn::ItemStruct`, but the compiler it's telling me: `no ItemStruct in the root.`

I am using `syn = "1.0.86"`, following this docs: `https://docs.rs/syn/1.0.86/syn/struct.ItemStruct.html`

Does anyone knows how to workaround this issue?

Minimal context:

```
fn parse(input: &ParseBuffer) -> syn::Result<Self> {
        let _struct = input.parse::<Struct>()?;

        let mut parsed_fields = Vec::new();

        for field in _struct.span.fields {
            let struct_attribute = StructField::try_from(&field)?;
                                            
            parsed_fields.push(struct_attribute);
        }
        ...
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation says:

> This is supported on crate feature `full` only.

That means you must enable the feature: in your `Cargo.toml`, replace

```
syn = "1.0.86"
```

with

```
syn = { version = "1.0.86", features = ["full"] }
```

Otherwise, the `syn` crate is compiled without that type definition.

Comment: Wow! I didn't notice. Thanks